# Trying to download a jpg using nodejs and curl (alt=media) from drive without success

Tags: google-drive-api

I have used the nodejs and then subsequently curl to use the `files/{fileid}?alt=media`.

I get data, that is not the problem.  but the data I get is short of the file size when I download from drive using  the browser and the file I download is definitely not a JPG. I examined the 1st bytes in HEX and the starting characters are wrong. But a lot of the subsequent characters are correct. I am assuming it is an encoding issue but I have burned about 4 hours trying everything I can think of.

The file I download using the nodejs API looks like this

```
00000000: fdfd fdfd 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0100 0001  ......JFIF......
```

The real file looks like this:

```
00000000: ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0100 0001  ......JFIF......
```

ffd8 is the correct starting bytes for a JPEG so the real file is correct.

Any ideas?

The ones I download using CURL look even more different so I am probably doing something wrong there.

Finally I stripped down code and executed a pure https function from node to the api:

```
        var  params = "";

        const options = {
          hostname: "www.googleapis.com",
          headers : {
            'Content-Type'      : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization'     : 'Bearer '+file_token.access_token,
          },
          port: 443,
          path: "/drive/v3/files/"+file_id+"/?alt=media",
          method: 'GET'
        };


        var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
            const statusCode = res.statusCode;
            const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];
            res.setEncoding('binary');
            var rawData = '';
            let rdata = [ ];
            res.on('data', function (chunk) { rdata.push(Buffer.from(chunk, 'binary')); rawData += chunk; });
            res.on('end', function () {
                try {
                    var rbinary = Buffer.concat(rdata);
                    fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/xxx.jpg", rdata);

                } catch (E) {
                    console.log(E);
                }
            })
        });
        req.write(params);
        req.end();
```

With this one I get even worse results:

```
0000000: efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 0010 4a46  ..............JF
```

Comment: maybe wrong content type?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your script is almost the correct. But there is one modification point. So can you modify as follows?

#### From :

```
fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/xxx.jpg", rdata);
```

#### To :

```
fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/xxx.jpg", rbinary);
```

#### Note :

- This supposes that your access token can be used for downloading files and Drive API is enabled at API console.

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Umopepisdn Thank you for your comment. When OP's script is seen, it is found that `var rbinary = Buffer.concat(rdata);` is used. But `rdata` is used for `fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/xxx.jpg", rdata);`. So I proposed to modify the variable from `rdata` to `rbinary`.